# Has anybody ever stored an mp3 in a redis cache?

Tags: redis

I'm new to redis, and I think I have a good use case for redis.   What I'm trying to do is to cache an mp3 file for a short time.  These MP3s are >2M in side, but I'm also only talking maybe 5-10 stored any any moment in time.  The TTL on them would be fairly short too, minutes, not hours, etc.

(disk persistence isn't an option).

So, what I'm wondering, do I need to get fancy and Base64 out the mp3 to store it?  Or can I simply set keyvalue=bytearray[]?

This redis hit will be from a web service, which in turn, gets it's data from a downstream service with disk hits.   So what I'm trying to do is to cache the mp3 file a short time on my middleware if you will.  I won't need to do it for every file, just the ones >2M so I don't have to keep going bak to the downstream servers and request the file from the disk again.

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly store them, and 2MB is nothing for redis to store.

Redis is binary safe and you don't need to base64 your data, just store via byte array in your favorite client.

One thing I'd consider doing (it might not be worth it with 2Mb of data, but if I were to store video files for example) is to store the file a sequence of chunks, and not load everything at once. If your app won't hold many files in memory at once, and the files are not that big, it might not be worth it. But if you're expecting high concurrency, do consider this as it will save application memory, not redis memory.

You can do this in a number of ways:

1. You can store each block as an element of a sorted set with the sequence number as score, and read them one by one, so you won't have to load everything to memory at once.
2. You can store the file a complete string, but read chunks with `GETRANGE`.

e.g.

```
GETRANGE myfile.mp3 0 10000
GETRANGE myfile.mp3 100000 200000
... #until you read nothing of course
```

Comment: I guess the next question would what method?   I'm using stackexchange.redis and the best I could find was StringSet(key,value).

Oh, the overall volume stored is actually going to be quite small.   It's mostly so I only have to hit the disk 1 time, not every time a partial content request comes in.

Comment: @NickJacobs I don't know the specific client, but this is the redis pattern I'd use.

Comment: All I ended up doing was this: 

                  //var converted = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    db.StringSet("12412", bytes, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 00));

Comment: @NickJacobs if your client supports binary data skip the base64 thing, it just wastes memory and cpu for no reason. saving it as raw binary will still allow you to stream the files in the future chunk by chunk if you ever need to